# List index out of range error in Python with Spark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I've been writing a code to view movives per year as a way to get into Spark environment.

My input is as such:

```
1|Toy Story (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Toy%20Story%20(1995)|0|0|0|1|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

As I couldn't get python to parse year from dateutils.parser, since the date format is not default to mm-dd-yyyy, I've decided to split it using split function.

```
lines = sc.textFile("file:///u.item") #pointing to input file
dates = lines.map(lambda x: x.split('|')[2].split('-')[2]) #parse date column first (01-Jan-1995) then extract the year by parsing '-', getting third index.

result = dates.countByValue()
```

This is the error I get,

```
18/04/23 17:14:23 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/04/23 17:14:30 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 229, in main
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 224, in process
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 372, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 845, in func
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1254, in countPartition
  File "C:/SparkFiles/ratings-counter.py", line 14, in <lambda>
    ratings = lines.map(lambda x: x.split('|')[2].split('-')[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The thing that I couldn't understand is when I use "split('-')[0]", I correctly get the day output. But when I try to extract month or year ([1], [2]), I get list index out of range error.

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess there are empty lines, or lines which do not have the format you specified. Look for that line. Change the `map` to a normal `for` loop and catch that line.

Comment: @mshsayem well, it seems that the input had a corrupted line, "267|unknown||||1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0". Sad to find that out after spending 3 hours. This should be a lesson to always check your input. Thanks!

Comment: btw, datetime should allowed you to parse it without split : `datetime.datetime.strptime('01-Jan-1995','%d-%b-%Y')`